# Cannot use Requests-Module on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to do a rest-call within a python script, that runs once per day.
I can't pack the "requests" package into my python-package using the AWS Lambdas. I get the error: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named lambda_function"

I broke it down to the hello_world predefined script. I can pack it into a zip and upload it. Everything works. As soon as I put "import requests" into the file, I get this error.

Here is what I already did:

1. The permissions of the zip and the project folder (including subfolders) are set to `chmod 777`. So permissions shouldn't be a problem.
2. The script itself is within the root folder. When you open the zip file, you directly see it.
3. I installed the requests package into the root-folder of the project using `sudo pip install requests -t PATH_TO_ROOT_FOLDER`

The naming of everything looks like this:

- zip-file: lambda_function.zip
- py-file: lambda_function.py
- handler method: lambda_handler(event, context)
- handler-definition in the "webconfig: lambda_function.lambda_handler

The file I want to run in the end looks like this:

```
import requests
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = 'xxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/users/login'
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic Zxxxxxxxxx3NjxxZxxxxzcw==" }
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    return 'hello lambda_handler'
```

I'm glad for ANY kind of help. I already used multiple hours on this issue.

Comment: In your question, the position of the `-t` option in the `pip install` command is incorrect - it must be `pip install requests -t PATH_TO_ROOT_FOLDER` . Did you just mistype it, or this is how you really ran it?

Comment: @Leon: Right. Just checked the history and I did it like you mention it here. :) So that didn't cause the problem.

Comment: What version of Python do you use locally?

Comment: @Leon: 2.7.12   (15chars)

Comment: Have you seen the guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html ?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes I followed those steps

Comment: Does the contents of your zip file suggest that the `requests` package was correctly added to it?

Comment: @Leon I just saw that the ZIP file did not contain the right structure. The files weren't in the "root" like I wrote in my question. Wtf man, such a dumb mistake. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I finally solved the problem: The structure in my zip file was broken. It is important that the python script and the packed dependencies (as folders) are in the root of the zip file. This solved my problem.

It's a bit depressing if you find such easy errors after hours of try and failure.

Comment: Does your script return json then? I'm trying to do similar, but keep getting 'not json serialisable'. I don't have 'import json' however... code works fine locally without 'import json' so not sure why it doesn't in Lambda.

Comment: @kafka You may need to import the json library. Not sure though, but AWS uses python 2.7 and not 3.x. My script doesn't return json.

Comment: yeah python 2.7 here. Going to attempt with explicit reference to json library. Currently re-packaging.

Comment: OK no joy here, in your code you simply return 'hello lambda_helper', I want to return the entire JSON response from the API Get though.... no worries if you don't know I might do a new question

Comment: I return status codes. But yeah, I'm not much into python. It was barely enough to write that script.

Comment: May I suggest that the answer goes one step further to clarify a crucial point? What does packed dependances mean? In this case, when you are zipping the packed contents you should do something like: zip package.zip -r * whilst in the directory containing the handler script and the dependances

Comment: Little more details please

Comment: Sorry guys, this question is so old, I cannot give a reliable answer anymore. That project I was working on is long gone. Packed dependencies meant dependencies as folders, that usually are in the root folder, but I can't give you any more on this sadly.

Comment: Is there any way without zipping and without using vendor modules?

Answer (score 235):

**EDIT: On Oct-21-2019 Botocore removed the vendored version of requests: https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1829**.

**EDIT 2: (March 10, 2020): The deprecation date for the Lambda service to bundle the requests module in the AWS SDK is now January 30, 2021. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/**

**EDIT 3: (Nov 22, 2022): AWS cancelled the deprecation so you can continue to use requests as described below. [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/)**

To use requests module, you can simply import `requests` from `botocore.vendored`. For example:

```
from botocore.vendored import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   response = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", timeout=10)
   print(response.json())
```

you can see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/4a052f39490fae00e0c3#file-list_aws_lambda_modules-py-L14) to know more modules that can be imported directly in AWS lambda.

Comment: Thank you. I've been driving myself insane trying to use `urllib2` (not as user friendly as `requests`)

Comment: Is there a concern that these might go away in later versions? " While these vendored dependencies are still in the botocore package they should not be used as they will be removed in the future"
https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html#upgrading-to-1-11-0

Comment: Wow. saved me from increasing my bundle size and keeping my lambda to few lines

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Helped people like me to save a lot of time.

Comment: FYI: I get a deprecation warning if i use this solution.

Comment: I would not use this method anymore. The official repo for botocore has a warning saying that botocore.vendored requests will be removed in the future.

Comment: So if this is being deprecated, what do we use now?

Comment: @MichaelBrant, you'll need to upload the requests library as part of your function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: A note - this no longer seems to work.  
```AttributeError: module 'botocore.vendored.requests' has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: @Penumbra this is because you are likely using Python 3.8.

Comment: Right, the blog says "The Lambda runtimes for Python 3.8 and later do not include the ‘requests’ module."

Answer (score 68):

If you're working with Python on AWS Lambda, and need to use **requests**, you better use [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html), it is currently supported on AWS Lambda and you can import it directly, check the example on urllib3 site.

```py
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/robots.txt')

r.data
# b'User-agent: *\nDisallow: /deny\n'
r.status
# 200
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 24):

I believe you have `lambda_function.py` on the Lambda console. You need to first create the Lambda function deployment package, and then use the console to upload the package.

- You create a directory, for example `project-dir` on your system (locally)
- create `lambda_function.py` in `project-dir`, copy the content of `lambda_function.py` from lambda console and paste it in `project-dir/lambda_function.py`
- `pip install requests -t /path/to/project-dir`
- Zip the content of the `project-dir` directory, which is your deployment package (Zip the directory content, not the directory)

Go to the Lambda console, select upload zip file in code entry type and upload your deployment package. Import requests should work without any error.

Comment: you can use `pip install requests -t .` (that's a dot after the -t) from within the directory containing your lambda_function.py rather than typing out the full project dir path. (form qarly_blue's answer). Bonus: Also works on windows

Answer (score 16):

Most of the comments somehow correct, but not enough informative for AWS beginners. Here is my long resume what needs to be done for accessing **requests** functionality:

###### 1. Creates root folder for AWS Lambda function

```
% mkdir lambda-function
```

###### 2. Go inside crated root folder

```
% cd lambda-function
```

###### 3. Create entry point Python file for AWS Lambda.

```
% vi lambda_function.py
```

###### 4. Paste a code into lambda_function.py

```
import requests
def lambda_handler(event, context):   
    response = requests.get("https://www.test.com/")
    print(response.text)
    return response.text
```

###### 5. Install requests library. Note:package folder created

```
% pip install --target ./package requests
```

###### 6. Go inside package

```
% cd package
```

###### 7. Zip package

```
zip -r ../deployment-package.zip .
```

###### 8. Go into parent folder

```
% cd ..
```

###### 9. Zip deployment packge and lambda function file

```
% zip -g deployment-package.zip lambda_function.py
```

1. In the AWS Lambda functions tap "**Upload from**" and pick "**.zip file**". Navigate to your zip package zip file: deployment-package.zip.
2. After upload all files will be inside AWS Lambda function.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

With this command download the folder package

```
pip install requests -t .
```

Run this command on your local machine, then zip your working directory, then upload to aws.

Comment: don't think this applies to AWS Lambda

Comment: this answer comined with the one below by pramod munemanik together is currently the best answer

Answer (score 8):

python 3.8 windows 10

lambda is looking for a specific folder structure and we are going to recreate in this manner in the steps below (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-create):
[image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-create]

1. make a folder on your desktop called "python," open a cmd terminal: cd desktop
2. pip install --target python requests
3. right click your python folder and zip it and rename the zip to 'requests.zip' - now if you look inside the zip you should see the python folder.
4. aws console > lambda > layers > create layer => name layer/upload requests.zip
5. aws console > functions > create function => in the "designer" box select layers and then "add layers." Choose custom layers and select
   your layer.
6. Go back to the function screen by clicking on the lambda symbol in the designer box. Now you can see "function code" again. Click lambda_function.py

Now you can import requests like this:

```
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    response = requests.get('your_URL')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response.json())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy whatever you have in the `lambda_function` fron AWS lambda console and paste it in a new python script and save it as `lambda_function.py`.
2. Make a new folder (I name it as *package*) and save `requests` module in it by running the following code in terminal:  **pip install -t *package* requests**
3. Move `lambda_function.py` into the folder (*package*).
4. Go to the folder and select all content and zip them.
5. Go back to the AWS Lambda console. select the function and under the Function code section, click on 'Action' (on the right side) and select `Upload a .zip file`.
6. Upload the folder. lambda_function should be uploaded automatically.
7. Run and Enjoy.

Comment: This is just [this 2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47903297/5067311) rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layer to your lambda function
by specifying this  arn (ap-south-1)

```
 arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p38-requests-html:10
```

Comment: Where does this ARN come from? Adding non-official code to your lambda seems like a dangerous action