# Send Post request to an external API using AWS Lambda in python

Tags: python, http-post, aws-lambda

I want to send a post request to an external API (https://example.com/api/jobs/test) every hour.

The Lambda Function that I used is as follows:

```
Handler: index.lambda_handler
python: 3.6
```

index.py

```
import requests
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  url="https://example.com/api/jobs/test"
  response = requests.post(url)
  print(response.text) #TEXT/HTML
  print(response.status_code, response.reason) #HTTP
```

Test Event:

```
 {
 "url": "https://example.com/api/jobs/test"
}
```

Error:

```
 START RequestId: 370eecb5-bfda-11e7-a2ed-373c1a03c17d Version: $LATEST
 Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'requests'

 END RequestId: 370eecb5-bfda-11e7-a2ed-373c1a03c17d
 REPORT RequestId: 370eecb5-bfda-11e7-a2ed-373c1a03c17d Duration: 0.65 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem isn't with your request, but with the module you're trying to import. Make sure it's installed. I'm not sure what that "index.php" is about, you are working with python, not php.

Comment: @FelisPhasma Thanks for the comment. Yes, but where the module should be installed? and sorry I meant index.py. it was typo mistake.

Comment: All good. You just need to install the requests module into your project directory.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following... Project Directory is it somewhere on AWS? (I'm new with Lambda)

Comment: Your `index.py` file is located somewhere on your aws server, and you should be able to install into the same directory as where that file is stored.

Comment: @FelisPhasma Sorry it might be stupid question... but I just when to AWS Lambda and created a function and it's not in VPC. I didn't use any EC2 server. Am I missing some setup?

Comment: no, not a stupid question. I think this answer can explain it better than I can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741282/cannot-use-requests-module-on-aws-lambda

Comment: this command should install requests for you, just make sure the root folder is specified properly: `pip install requests -t PATH_TO_ROOT_FOLDER`

Comment: http.client is supported natively. It's not quite as friendly as requests, but it is faster and will usually get the job done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install `requests` module to your project directory and create a lambda deployment package. See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) link for details.

In short, you need to create your index.py file on you development system (PC or mac), install Python & pip on that system; them follow the steps in the doc. To create lambda, choose the 'Upload zip' option instead of the 'Edit inline' one

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm wondering if I need to setup an EC2 server for installing the module? Because at the moment I just went to AWS Lambda and created a function. Is there something more that should be set?

Comment: No. You need to do these things (install python & pip, install requests using pip, zip the bundle etc.) on a system. Doesn't need to be EC2; can be your Windows PC or mac

Comment: @Matrix it would only need to be on an EC2 server (one running Amazon Linux specifically) if you needed to install binary dependencies. You don't need to do that for the `requests` module.

Comment: Thank you, I've created a directory(project_dir) and installed "requests" using pip and the created post.py file in the dir after that zipped it via cd project_dir; zip -r ../post_dir.zip * now I got this error: This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries.

Answer (score 31):

Vendored `requests` are now removed from `botocore`.

Consider packaging your Lambda code with `requirements.txt` using CloudFormation package or SAM CLI packaging functionality.

> My older answer from before vendored `requests` deprecation:
>   You may be able to leverage `requests` module from the `boto` library without having to install or package your function.
>
> Consider this import:
>   `import botocore.vendored.requests as requests`

Comment: This is a much better option. Why were there no vote-ups?

Comment: It’s a brand new answer :)

Comment: This method of importing the requests is depreciated is it not?

Comment: There is just deprecation warning, but that by itself doesn't mean much.

Comment: Please note that an upcoming change to Botocore will be removing the vendored version of the requests library in Botocore: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/

Comment: i use this 'pip install requests boto3 mock --upgrade --user' still getting error in REST end point call. Jenkins build was success, and when i invoke the REST my response in internal server error and when i see the logs, unable to import module requests.

Comment: @parrotjack maybe the requests vendored module is already gone from botocore :(

Comment: @kixorz yeah i read the aws article, the mentioned to install requests, and installed it using the commands but still occurs.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/
New updates on deprecations

Comment: It's better to move off botocore.vendored.requests ASAP anyway.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried using botocore and spent hours figuring out why my code wasn't working

Answer (score -1):

You need to install requests module. Type :

```
pip install requests
```

into your terminal, or after activating virtual environment if you are using one.