# Trying to query an API from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, function, aws-lambda

I'm trying to query an open source API that returns IP geolocation information by sending a GET request with the IP.

I'm testing the code with a key that contains an IP address (located in `key1`). I'm trying to fetch the information after the request is sent but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried appending the IP to the end of the url (as the geoip API instructs) but I keep getting syntax errors.

```py
import json
from botocore.vendored import requests

def lambda_handler(resp, requests, event):

    event = event.key1

    url = "https://freegeoip.app/json/" +event

    headers = {
        'accept': "application/json",
        'content-type': "application/json"
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)
```

I have the code working in regular python syntax below, just don't know how to get it working with lambda

```
import requests


userIP = '54.81.183.174'

def theFunction():
  url = "https://freegeoip.app/json/" + userIP

  headers = {
        'accept': "application/json",
        'content-type': "application/json"
        }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

  print(response.text)

theFunction()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using the `requests` module, which is not installed with AWS Lambda.

You can package it for use with an AWS Lambda function (see [python - Cannot use Requests-Module on AWS Lambda - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741282/cannot-use-requests-module-on-aws-lambda)), but it is simpler to use `urllib`, which is part of standard Python3.

Here is some code that works:

```py
import urllib.request
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  ip = event['ip']

  with urllib.request.urlopen("https://freegeoip.app/json/" + ip) as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

  print(data)
  print(data['city'])
```

You can trigger it with test data:

```
{
  "ip": "54.81.183.174"
}
```

Comment: Wow this has been bugging me for hours and was so simple. Thanks! I have one question though, why is the response null even though the logs get me the info I wanted?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer that (eg what do you mean by "the logs get me the info I wanted"), but it might also be due to the incorrect parameters in the `lambda_handler()` function.

Comment: That is my fault! I forgot to include my callback function after I had taken it out for debugging.

Comment: would I be able to send the test data as a list?

Comment: The data is sent to the Lambda function as a string, which is then interpreted as a JSON object. You can pass a list as JSON: `[1, 2, 3]` then use it in a loop (eg `for ip in event:`

Comment: How would that translate to a query string?

Comment: It doesn't. You will need to loop through each value in the list, create an appropriate query string, the retrieve the URL.